# 12AM time lost/not displaying in mapping interface

Tags: javascript, sql-server, arcgis-server

The time values are currently being displayed in our ArcGIS API for JavaScript mapping service correctly except for midnight 12AM (it does not display a time, only the date). We are displaying the DATETIME1 field in our mapping service. It is displaying as EST.

The polygons are stored in a SQL Server table. In our SQL Server the DATETIME1 field for midnight for 1/1/13 would contain:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

and for 1 A.M:

```
2013-01-01 01:00:00.0000000
```

I'm not entirely sure where to begin. Would this be a JavaScript issue or would I need to store times differently in SQL Server? Thank you. I am new to my current job and have inherited this large project. It may take me a bit to find files/code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to achieve this:

```
Select convert(varchar(20),getdate(),120)
```

also, if you want additional zeros at the end:

```
convert(varchar(20),getdate(),120)+'.0000000'
```